# Jumping over elements that have not the same HTML tag while webscraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, data-cleaning

I´m currently trying to webscrape the percentage saved between two different prices. The HTML code for the first element that I want to webscrape is:

```
<li class="price-save">
    <span class="price-save-endtime price-save-endtime-current"></span>
    <span class="price-save-endtime price-save-endtime-another" style="display:none;"></span>
    <span class="price-save-label">Save: </span>
    <span class="price-save-dollar"></span>
    <span class="price-save-percent">22%</span>   <----------------------I WANT THIS ONE!
</li>
```

To do this, I coded the following in Python:

```
try:
    percentage = soup.find('span',class_='price-save-percent').get_text()
except:
    print("Not found")
```

However, when I print the results into a .csv file if the next element of the website does not contain the % then it copies the result until it finds the next element with a percentage. For a better understanding, please, see the url: `https://www.newegg.com/Laptops-Notebooks/SubCategory/ID-32?Tid=6740`

You can see that the first element has `% Save`, second one as well, but the third one no. In the `.csv` file, the third element gets the % saved of the second one. This happends repeteadly. Instead, I would like to have just a blank cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the NA condition for each item in the list. To do that you need to be in the grid with only relevant div items. Below code does the job and saves all the price_saved in a list if available else appends NA-:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv
#Link de la pàgina on farem webscraping
url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Laptops-Notebooks/SubCategory/ID-32?Tid=6740'

#Obrim una connexió amb la pàgina web
Client = req(url)
#Offloads the content of the page into a variable
pagina = Client.read()
#Closes the client
Client.close()
#html parser
pagina_soup=soup(pagina,"html.parser")
#grabs each product
productes = pagina_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

 #Obrim un axiu .csv
#Capçaleres del meu arxiu .csv
result_file = open("ordinadors.csv",'a',encoding='utf-8',newline='')
 #Escrivim la capçalera
head = ["Marca","Producte","PreuActual","PreuAnterior","CostEnvio","Rebaixa"]
writing_csv = csv.DictWriter(result_file, fieldnames=head)
writing_csv.writeheader()

#Fem un loop sobre tots els productes
for producte in productes:

    #Agafem la marca del producte
    marca_productes = producte.findAll("div",{"class":"item-info"})
    marca = marca_productes[0].div.a.img["title"]

    #Agafem el nom del producte
    name = producte.a.img["title"] 

    #Preu Actual
    actual_productes = producte.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
    preuActual = actual_productes[0].strong.text

    #Preu anterior    
    try:
        #preuAbans = producte.find("li", class_="price-was").next_element.strip()
        preuAbans = producte.find('span',class_='price-was-data').get_text()
        percentage = producte.find('span',class_='price-save-percent').get_text()
    except:
        preuAbans = "NA"
        percentage = "NA"

    #Agafem els costes de envio
    costos_productes = producte.findAll("li",{"class":"price-ship"})
    #Com que es tracta d'un vector, agafem el primer element i el netegem.
    costos = costos_productes[0].text.strip()  

    #Writing the file
    writing_csv.writerow({"Marca": marca, "Producte": name, "PreuActual": preuActual, "PreuAnterior": preuAbans,"CostEnvio":costos,"Rebaixa":percentage})

result_file.close()
```

Comment: When doing this, I get the following error when printing the file into the .csv.
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: I´ve modified the post. Added .csv file code and also saving variable into your code

Comment: the edit you have made for writing the csv is incomplete. The variables are undefined . I would suggest you give the value of variables  like marca, name , etc

Comment: the other variables work fine and are correctly exported into the .csv file. I just added all the line but the problem appears when I added this one.

Comment: I can only help if you provide the source of what are you actually trying to do

Comment: Hey the original question was very different from the one you asked now. Although i have made the changes with required csv generated but going forward if the problem is different ask another question, rather than creeping scope in comments